# camerasubject not working on roblox studio

Tags: roblox

i have problems with the camerasubject in
roblox studio.

**This is my code.**

```
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    wait(2)
    workspace.Camera.CameraSubject = workspace.Camera1["Almost dead person"].Humanoid
    workspace.Camera.CameraType = Enum.CameraType.Scriptable
    wait(4)
    workspace.Camera.CameraSubject = workspace.Camera2["Almost dead person"].Humanoid
    wait(1)
    workspace.Camera.CameraType = Enum.CameraType.Fixed
    workspace.Camera:Destroy()
end)
```

Comment: Could you edit your question and clarify what your problem is? When you say it's not working, what do you expect to happen and what is actually happening? Are there any errors showing up in the Output window?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the problem would be on line 3 and line 6, it seems to be caused by you having a ["object name"], you cant continue the selection after a object spaced name bracket, my fix will be renaming Almost dead person to Almost_dead_person and update the name in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Your `CameraSubject` needs to be its own separate child of `Camera` since there is no `.` to add another child.